# FileMaker Pro: <no values defined>

Tags: filemaker

So im working on a Hardware Inventory and I have a problem with my Relationships.

In my "item_view" layout i would like to select a type and then a brand that corresponds to the unique type ( i.e. if i select the type "Smartphone" it should show me all brands for Smartphones ). The attribute "type" is defined in a own table ( seen in the picture below ), such as brand ( model and designation are there too, but i've tried only the type-brand thing first - "testing db" ).

My problem is that if i try to access to the "type" table in the "item_view" layout, i can select a type but not a related brand (  ). I made a "pop-up menu" in the "item_brand" field and gave him values from "brand::brand" with "include only related values starting from: type" ( actually its "typ", but thats german for type - so ignore that ).

I think that should work, but i't doesn't. So i need help. thx.

[image: Here you can see the pictures :)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect your `item_view` table occurrence to your `typ` table occurrence via the relationship:

```
 item_view::item_typ = typ::typ_id
```

Which would look like this: [image]

You should be able to create a value list using the `brand` table that shows related records starting at `typ`: 
[image]

[image]

This way, when you select a particular type, that `typ` record can be used to look down the relationship

```
typ -> connect -> brand
```

to see all of the related brands. You can then attach that value list as a popup menu or dropdown list to the `item_brand` field on your item_view layout to allow you to pick a related brand.

[image]

It should be noted that you're showing all text brand values, but all you're storing in the `item_view` table is the ID of the brand you selected. The field names in your `item_view` table should be `type_id` and `brand_id`, because that's what you'd actually be storing in the fields.

You could create a similar value list for type to use the `type_id` and `type_name` so that when you're using a popup menu what you SEE is the `typ::type` value but what you're STORING in the `item_view` table is the `typ::typ_id` value.

I Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Chris, i tried it but it doesnt worked. I thing i dont need a connection between item_view and the typ-brand table, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Wondux, yes you would need the connection between `item_view` and `type-brand`. The relationship will allow you to show related brands. The connection would allow `item_view` records to see a related `typ` records. Once the related `typ` record is accessible from `item_view` it means you can see all of it's related records down the relationship graph.

Comment: now it worked. Im new with databases so i didnt know that i had to use only the id's to fix my problem. Big Thanks.

Comment: how can i add 2 more attributes to the item_view ( i.e. typ: "smartphone", brand: "apple", model: "iPhone 3G", designation: "A1241" )? I tried to do it like type and brand, with a join-table but its very buggy. Sometimes it shows not the correct models and somtimes it does, but then i have the wrong designation. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: To add another attribute that is based on the brand you just need to create a `model` table that has a `brand_id`  foreign key and link it to brand via the relationship `brand::brand_id = model::brand_id`. This will create a one to many relationship between brand (1) and model (many). From there you can add a `model_id` field to your `item_view` and create a new value list similar to the brand one that shows model ids and values starting from related brand records. The only time you need to include a join table is of you need a many to many relationship.